# Is it possible to move a WordPress site from localhost of one machine to localhost of another machine?

Tags: wordpress, localhost, backup

I made a website (70% done) in wordpress using xampp in my home PC,But now I need to move the existing work from my PC to my friend's PC to do the rest 30% work.

There are some plugins I found like duplicator , WPBackup etc. but through them it is possible to transfer the site to a server through ftp or some other way.
So I was wondering if there is any plugin or some other way to solve this issue, (like transferring a zipped folder to other machine)

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You need all source files and the database.  Make a copy of the database (in phpmyadmin you can export to file). Then move the whole site directory to your friend's computer (a external hard drive will work).  When on your friends' site, be sure to import the database and make sure that the wp-config.php file reflects db name, password and location (probably localhost) for your friends Xampp setup.

Answer (score 1):

Duplicator would work great for this - I often use it when moving from one local environment to another. You would simply need to run the plugin, save the files to a flashdrive/cloud, then upload those files to your new machine.

It's also fairly simple to do manually. Simply export your database from phpMyAdmin and upload it into phpMyAdmin on your new machine.

Comment: Thanks,I tried duplicator, but i'm not getting any options for uploading on the other machine .  . . I mean how to use the installer.php file on that computer?

Answer (score 0):

Copy all wordpress files to the new machine, create the database on the new machine, import the existing db to the new machine, make sure that the paths are the same, for example if it was localhost:8888/site make sure that is the same. Then you are ready to go.